# Getting error as could not convert string to float

Tags: logistic-regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lm=LogisticRegression()

lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_33228\2051686732.py in 
----> 1 lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
1506             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
1507
-> 1508         X, y = self._validate_data(
1509             X,
1510             y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
582             out = X, y
583

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
962         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
963
--> 964     X = check_array(
965         X,
966         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
744                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
745                 else:
--> 746                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
747             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
748                 raise ValueError(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **array**(self, dtype)
2062
2063     def **array**(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 2064         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
2065
2066     def **array_wrap**(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'B77'